# Making Ajax call from static FBML page

Tags: ajax, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I have one FBML static page added as a tag in my Facebook page. 
It is basically a newsletter sign up. I want the page to submit via Ajax to an external website, get the response and show the response message in the Facebook tab. 
Is it possible in this scenario using FBJS?

Here is my newsletter HTML which is used to draw the tab.

```
<div id="response_msg"></div>
<div class="register">
  <form  id="newsletter_signup" action="http://my webserver page/" method="post">
     <h1>Register for updates</h1>
      <ul>
         <li><label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="hint" value="" name="first_name">
         </li>
         <li><label>Last Name</label>
             <input type="text" class="hint" value="" name="last_name">
         </li>
         <li><label>Email</label>
             <input type="text" class="hint" value="" name="email">
         </li>
         <li>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" > 
         </li>
     </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this once
http://www.pqinternet.com/229.htm